# dropzone js onclick submit file upload

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

upload all files with a single button click.
HTML:

```html
<button id="submit-all">Submit all files</button>
<form action="/target" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
```

JS:

```js
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,

  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
        myDropzone = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    });

    // You might want to show the submit button only when 
    // files are dropped here:
    this.on("addedfile", function() {
      // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
    });

  }
};
```

But the file is upload after drag and drop..

Answer (score 55):

use simple code

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(element, {
  url: "/upload.php",                        
  autoProcessQueue: false,
});

$('#imgsubbutt').click(function(){           
  myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

Comment: This is very clean approach of doing this. But you missed following line before this code.

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

If we don't add this, we will get error, something like "Dropzone already attached"

Comment: What's `element` in the `new Dropzone...` line?

Comment: gokul_uf element is DOM

Comment: For anyone stumped by the DOM element bit - jQuery doesn't return native DOM elements by default so you need to tell it to by adding `get(0)` like so: `$('#myDropzone').get(0)` - see here for more info: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Answer (score 21):

I accomplished this by placing my dropzone in a div instead of a form, thereby removing the ability for dropzone to automatically `POST` the uploads to a given URL.  The URL I passed to the dropzone instance when I created it is literally 'dummy' since it will never be called. For example, 
HTML

```html
<button id="submit-all">Submit all files</button>
<div class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></div>
```

JavaScript

```js
$('#submit-all').on('click', function() {
    var files = $('#my-dropzone').get(0).dropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
    // Do something with the files.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here how i implement delayed uploading (initiated by click on any button, for an example):

Dropzone implementation

```
var count = 0;
var addedFilesHash = {};
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#file_upload-form", {
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    parallelUploads: 5,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*,.xlsx,.xls,.pdf,.doc,.docx",
    maxFiles: 10,
    init: function() {
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
            // delete from our dict removed file
            delete addedFilesHash[file];
        });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        var _id = count++;
        file._id = _id;
        addedFilesHash[_id] = done;
    }
});
```

Somewhere else

```
    // get all uploaded files in array
    var addedFiles = Object.keys(addedFilesHash);
    // iterate them
    for (var i = 0; i< addedFiles.length; i++) {
        // get file obj
        var addedFile = addedFiles[i];
        // get done function
        var doneFile = addedFilesHash[addedFile];
        // call done function to upload file to server
        doneFile();
    }
```

We override `accept` and `removedFile` functions. In `accept` function we collect   `file` objects and `done` functions in dict where key is `file` and value is `done` function. Later in time, when we are ready to upload added files, we are iterating all `done` functions for all files in dict `addedFilesHash` which launches upload progress with progress bar and etc.

Answer (score 2):

I got just finished messing around with this myself- I wanted to add information about the image to a database at the same time as uploading it. Dropping a file opens the input form for the extra info and then the queue needs sending after the form button is pressed.

I finally achieved this by putting a jquery click event handler inside the init 'on add file' function event:

```js
this.on("addedfile", function(file){
  var myDropzone = this;
  $('#imageinfoCont').animate({left:'4.5%'});//brings form in
  $('#imgsubbutt').click(function(){
    $('#imageinfoCont').animate({left:'-10000px'}); //hides the form again
    myDropzone.processQueue(); //processes the queue
  });
});
```

I am then adding the extra data in a separate 'on sending' function event (could probably do it in the above code but baby steps I think).

Seems to work like a charm.

Comment: If you add multiple files, you are re-attaching `click` to each one.  If you add two files, you will call myDropzone.processQueue twice.  Write a `console.log` within the click method and see if it attaches twice.

Answer (score 1):

Although this has been answered, I ran into a situation where I only wanted to submit the queue IF it was a certain type of file.  The bug I ran into was it was ignoring `processQueue`.

```
  this.dropzone = new Dropzone('#my-dropzone', {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
  });
  return this.dropzone.on('addedfile', (function(_this) {
    return function(file) {

      var IMAGE_EXTENSIONS, ext;
      IMAGE_EXTENSIONS = 'png jpg jpeg gif'.split(' ');
      ext = (_.last(file.name.split('.'))).toLowerCase();

      if (_.include(IMAGE_EXTENSIONS, ext)) {
        return console.log('IMAGE!');
      } else {

        return setTimeout(function() { // HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          return _this.dropzone.processQueue();
        }, 10);
      }
    };
  })(this));
```

I had to use the setTimeout seen above because `processQueue` did nothing if I didn't defer it in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Working example

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone('.dropzone-file', {
url: "https://keenthemes.com/scripts/void.php", // Set the url for your upload script location
paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
addRemoveLinks: true,
uploadMultiple: true,
autoProcessQueue: false,
});

$('.upload-files').on('click', function() {
var files = $('.dropzone-file').get(0).dropzone.getAcceptedFiles();

//upload bar
$('.dz-upload').addClass('dz-progress-bar');

// Do something with the files.
console.log(files)
});
```

```css
.dropzone-file{
border: 1px dashed green;
padding: 1%;
text-align: center;
}
.dropzone-file:hover{
cursor:pointer;
background:whitesmoke;
}
@-webkit-keyframes passing-through {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
        -o-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
    }
    30%,
    70% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
        -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
        transform: translateY(-40px);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes passing-through {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
        -o-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
    }
    30%,
    70% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
        -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
        transform: translateY(-40px);
    }
}
@keyframes passing-through {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
        -o-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
    }
    30%,
    70% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
        -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
        transform: translateY(-40px);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
        -o-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
        -o-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
@keyframes slide-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
        -o-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    10% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    10% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    10% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
.dropzone-file,
.dropzone-file * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropzone-file {
    min-height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
.dropzone-file.dz-clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropzone-file.dz-clickable * {
    cursor: default;
}
.dropzone-file.dz-clickable .dz-message,
.dropzone-file.dz-clickable .dz-message * {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropzone-file.dz-started .dz-message {
    display: none;
}
.dropzone-file.dz-drag-hover {
    border-style: solid;
}
.dropzone-file.dz-drag-hover .dz-message {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-message {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em 0;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-message .dz-button {
    background: none;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: inherit;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 16px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview:hover {
    z-index: 1000;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview:hover .dz-details {
    opacity: 1;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-image {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #999;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee, #ddd);
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-details {
    opacity: 1;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview.dz-image-preview {
    background: #fff;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview.dz-image-preview .dz-details {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-remove {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-remove:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview:hover .dz-details {
    opacity: 1;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-details {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 2em 1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    line-height: 150%;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-size {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename:hover span {
    border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename:not(:hover) {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename:not(:hover) span {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-filename span,
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-details .dz-size span {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    padding: 0 0.4em;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview:hover .dz-image img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    filter: blur(8px);
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-image {
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-image img {
    display: block;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview.dz-success .dz-success-mark {
    -webkit-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -moz-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -ms-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -o-animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    animation: passing-through 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-error-mark {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -moz-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -ms-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -o-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-success-mark,
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-error-mark {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -27px;
    margin-top: -27px;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-success-mark svg,
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-error-mark svg {
    display: block;
    width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview.dz-processing .dz-progress {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview.dz-complete .dz-progress {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview:not(.dz-processing) .dz-progress {
    -webkit-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
    -ms-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
    animation: pulse 6s ease infinite;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-progress {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1000;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 16px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-progress .dz-upload {
    background: #333;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #666, #444);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview.dz-error .dz-error-message {
    display: block;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview.dz-error:hover .dz-error-message {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-error-message {
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
    top: 130px;
    left: -10px;
    width: 140px;
    background: #be2626;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #be2626, #a92222);
    padding: 0.5em 1.2em;
    color: #fff;
}
.dropzone-file .dz-preview .dz-error-message:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 64px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #be2626;
}
.dz-progress-bar {
    width: 0;
    animation: progress 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  } 
  
  @keyframes progress {
    from {
      width: 0;
    }
    to {
      width: 100%;
    }
  } 
  @keyframes show  {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.css" type="text/css" />

<!--begin::Dropzone-->
<div class="dropzone-file fileuploader">
<!--begin::Message-->
<div class="dz-message needsclick">
<!--begin::Icon-->
<i class="bi bi-file-earmark-arrow-up text-primary fs-3x"></i>
<!--end::Icon-->

<!--begin::Info-->
<div class="ms-4">
<h3 class="fs-5 fw-bolder text-gray-900 mb-1">Drop files here or click to upload.</h3>
<span class="fs-7 fw-bold text-gray-400">Upload any kind of files</span>
</div>
<!--end::Info-->
</div>
</div>
<!--end::Dropzone-->

<button class='upload-files'>Upload Files</button>
```